# JavaScript framework selectors that support older browsers like jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, cross-browser, css-selectors

I want to make my own personal JavaScript framework, everything was going good and then we got to the selectors... I've tested in some of the older browsers and well it doesn't seem to work right or sometimes at all how can I can get these selectors to support:

```
IE6+(6,7,8,9,10,11)
Chrome(1+)
Firefox(1+)
Safari(5+)
Opera(10+)
Ios(5+)
Android(2.3+)
```

I don't want to use jQuery sizzle or any other plugin or library, here is my code so far:

```
  function selector(element){
    if(!(this instanceof selector)){
      return new selector(element);
    }else if(!element){
      return this;
    }else if(element instanceof selector){
      return element;
    }else if(element.nodeType){
      return this[0] = element, this.length = 1, this;
    }else if("string" === typeof element){
      return e.apply(this, f.call(c.querySelectorAll(element)));
    }else if("function" === typeof element){
      return selector(c).ready(element);
    }
  }
```

thank you in advance - Millze.

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what the posted code is doing since `e`, `f`, and `c` are created/initialized elsewhere and thus effectively black boxes. One thing to check though would be [caniuse.com/queryselector](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector). When you click on the Show All button above the results, you'll see that `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are not supported in all your target browsers.

Comment: Any browser that doesn't support `querySelectorAll()` doesn't natively support CSS selectors in JS, period. If you're not going to use a library or implement it yourself, you will not get it to work.

Comment: So, be prepared to reinvent the Sizzle "wheel", probably badly. Hopefully this is for educational purposes.

Comment: Already working on it...